# Webform periodically returns this error

Tags: 7, webforms

Hi I have 2 fairly complex webforms, one with 2 pages and the other with 4. This error shows up often, but not consistently - when saving drafts or moving between pages. I used the Webform Template module to make a copy of the 4 page form and then deleted the last 2 pages for the 2 page form as the first 2 pages are the same.

[image: webform error]

Any idea what could be causing this? 
Reloading the pages will most times fix, occasionally it will show twice in a row.

PHP 5.6, Drupal 7.39, Webform 7.x-4.11, Webform Template 7.x-4.0, Webform Validation 7.x-1.10, WebForm 2 PDF 7.x-4.0

Thanks!